# Symfony 2 split application to more bundles

Tags: symfony, bundle

I want to split my application to two bundles.

Back-end bundle which will be something like CMS admin(reusable to another projects), and Front-end bundle.

I moved whole backend application including controllers, templates and model to new bundle, but I have a problem with 3rd-party bundles on which my project is dependent.

For example AsseticBundle. When I add assetic configuration to BackendBundle/config.yml i recieve a exception.

```
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "assetic"
```

Is there some good tutorial showing how to split application to two cooperating bundles with one config and both dependent to 3rd-party libraries?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to add 3rd party bundle configuration to your own bundle config.

This can be achieved only in `app/config/config.yml`, which is loaded by default by Symfony. It's the only place where Symfony looks.

What you can do, is prepend configuration via own extension. That can be placed in your bundle:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\PrependExtensionInterface;

class BackendBundleExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface
{
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->prependExtensionConfig('assetic', array(
            'key' => 'value'
        ));
    }
}
```

Let me know, if this is sufficient explanation.

Comment: I do not need add configuration, I have problem with referencing 3rd-party bundles from my not-AppBundle. I think they are not registred, because I register them in AppKernel.php in app folder and I think it's only for AppBundle. I am asking how to use them in not-AppBundle too.

Comment: I see. AppKernel.php registers all the bundles. It's the correct place to put them. Let's take your error message. Do you have AssetisBundle there?
If so, where do you put your 'assetic` configuration? And how do you load it to `app/config/config.yml`?